# If/else JavaScript statement with multiple div traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check a set of divs with id='checkbox-selector-chosen' to see if a dynamic variable *name* exists in those divs. The code below works only if one 'checkbox-selector-chosen' div exists. What I'm trying to do is get the code below to check all of the 'checkbox-selector-chosen' divs for the existence of *name*.

```
if($(".checkbox-selector-chosen").text() == name) {
   do something...
}
```

The structure of the divs I'm working with is as follows:

```
<div id="selected-results" class="group">
  <div class="checkbox-selector-chosen">John</div>
  <div class="checkbox-selector-chosen">Dave</div>
  <div class="checkbox-selector-chosen">Jack</div>
</div>
```

I'm new to JS/JQuery and I'm sure this is a simple problem, but after 2 days of banging my head against my desk I've decided to ask on here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the [:contains() selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to see if the item exists ([JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kMZc/1/))

```
var name='Dave';

//Get all items that contain 'Dave'
var items = $(".checkbox-selector-chosen:contains('" + name + "')");

if (items.length > 0) {
    alert(items.length + ' items found');
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you're worried about having more than one matching item, you can use my example, AND the `each()` function. ([JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kMZc/2/)). The Beauty of this approach is that you do not have to loop through all of the child divs - you only need to loop through the divs that contain the desired matching text.

```
var name='Dave';

//Get all items that contain 'Dave'
var items = $(".checkbox-selector-chosen:contains('" + name + "')");

if (items.length > 0) {
    items.each(function(){
        if ($(this).html()==name){
           alert('item found!');
           break;
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is an example which demonstrates the full use of this technique. When you click on a name div, the name is parsed from the object that is clicked and the we use the above method to find the right div. This is, of course, not the best way to accomplish this specific task, but simple illustrates the concept. ([JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5kMZc/3/))

```
function findName(name){
    var items = $(".checkbox-selector-chosen:contains('" + name + "')");
    $('.checkbox-selector-chosen').css({'background':'#fff'});
    if (items.length > 0) {
        items.each(function(){
            if ($(this).text()==name){
                $(this).css({'background':'#ff0'});
            }
        });
    }
}

$('.checkbox-selector-chosen').click(function(){
   findName($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your first solution worked a treat! 

I tried to use :contains() but could not figure out how to get a dynamic variable to work, only static ones did. I don't have to bang my head against the desk anymore :)

Comment: You're most welcome. Just remember that anything that goes inside of `$(...)` is a string selector. Being that it is a string, you can concatenate variables and literal strings at will to create the perfect selector for your needs. Just make sure your names don't have any apostrophes or you will need to escape your name string. If name is `O'neil` you will need to search for `O\'neil`

Comment: Seriously, thanks for your time. Just out of interest do you do any freelance work? I'm currently working on a project and it would be brilliant to reach out to someone like yourself for some expert advice/work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use jQuery [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="selected-results" class="group">
      <div class="checkbox-selector-chosen">John</div>
      <div class="checkbox-selector-chosen">Dave</div>
      <div class="checkbox-selector-chosen">Jack</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(".checkbox-selector-chosen:contains(John)").css("background-color","red")
    </script>        
  </body>
</html>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/owiloz/)

Comment: What if there is a name div that says `John` and another that says `John Smith`? Both divs will be effected. It's best to use a combination of both `:contains()` and `each()`. Also the literal string `John` should be in quotes like this `$(".checkbox-selector-chosen:contains('John')")`

Answer (score 1):

Your class selector returns a collection of matches. You could try `each()` to iterate over them:

```
$(".checkbox-selector-chosen").each( function() {
  if ($(this).text() == name) {
    /* ..do something... */
  } } );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.checkbox-selector-chosen').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == name) {
        do something...
    }
});
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for?
ahh beaten to it!

Answer (score 1):

You can user jquery 'each' syntax for this.

```
   $(".checkbox-selector-chosen").each(function(index, value){
    console.info("index = "+index +" = "+value);
    if(value == name){
        console.info("match");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `contains()` selector to filter the results:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var checked = this.checked;
    $('.checkbox-selector-chosen')
     .filter(":contains("+this.value+")")
     .css('color',function(){
       if (checked) return "red";  
          else return "black";
     });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/mww3J/